# Can you use a PCIe 16x card in a PCIe 1x slot?

Tags: pci-express

Can this be done at all? Can this be done with a riser?

I want to use two PCIe 16x cards in the two other slots i have on my motherboard that are PCIe 1x.

Can it be done?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

Yes it can be done, provided that motherboard manufacturers provide a space between the slots big enough for your x16 expansion card to fit in **and** the PCIe x1 has an open end. Note that not all manufacturers provide this option. However, the card will operate slower than it is supposed to. You will provide it 1 lane instead of 16 lanes.

Further reading: [Hardware Secrets: Everything You Need to Know About the PCI-Express](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/article/Everything-You-Need-to-Know-About-the-PCI-Express/190/4).

Comment: You could, alternately use a riser. Can't think of any reason someone would do this, outside bitcoin mining,