# I'm trying to upgrade to a new GPU, need some help identifying whats in my PCIe x 4 slot

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, pci-express

I'm trying to upgrade to a [GTX 770](http://www.nvidia.com/gtx-700-graphics-cards/gtx-770/) from a single slot GPU, however, it requires two PCI slots, and all mine are occupied. I know whats in one of the slots (not including GPU), but I need help identifying what this red-circled slot is.
[image]

I want to know if I can remove it as well. Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified, I also forgot to include the image of my pc. http://imgur.com/yFcGRQ0. I know I can remove the one to the right of the circled slot, however, I still am unable to identify what the circled slot is. I've checked for a model number and everything. No luck.

Comment: That is a really bad image, it would probably help to know what those wires connect to, and there is clearly some text on the card that is not readable on the image. Do you know what the other two cards are? It is strange to see that you have run out of slots as every common component but a high end video card is usually found directly on the motherboard.

Comment: I don't understand this question. Why do you want to identify the *slot*? You wouldn't be removing the slot, you'd be removing whatever was in it -- and you don't give us any clue what that is.

Answer (score 3):

GTX 770 does not require 2 PCI slots. It has one connector, that is PCIe x16. (the little part to the left of the connector is for power and the rest is for data connections).

[image]

In your image, all the black ones (except for RAM slots) are PCI-Express (PCIe) slots. Longest ones are x16, smallest one is x1 and the one you red-circled is the x4 slot of PCIe. You can install your graphics card to any of those (even though it has x16 lanes), your graphics card will work. However, for the **best performance** you have to install your graphics card to a **x16 slot**.

[image]

More about PCIe: you can install PCIe of any length (x1, x4, x8, x16) to a slot of any length.  Means that you can install a x1 device to a x8 slot or x16 slot to a x4 slot. However, you should choose the slot according to the length of your device for best performance.

To clarify things: you provided an empty slot image and asking for what is in there. Can be anything with a PCIe connector. You should check back of the chassis for connections, maybe you can identify what hardware is installed on that slot. Furthermore you can change its position. If you have the other PCIe x16 slot empty, you can install the PCIe x4 device there, or even to the x1. So that you can get enough room for your new GPU.

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/690409/can-you-use-a-pcie-16x-card-in-a-pcie-1x-slot/690411), considering room for relatively larger GPUs, might interest you as well.

Comment: The card most likely has a cooler that extends into the neighbouring slot, thus making it impossible to use that slot. Practically all modern high-end video cards are designed this way.

Comment: You can't install most graphics cards in anything but an x16 slot. The other slots don't supply enough power. (Only an x16 slot is required to provide up to 75W and most graphics cards draw from the slot more than an x8 is required to provide.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz For powerful GPUs, don't provide power from the 6 pin PCIe power connector from PSU ?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz and as far as I know, power supply lanes are identical for slots in any length. Also, I have never heard that using GPUs in smaller lanes (even though it makes no sense, they just work in smaller lanes) caused _power_ problems. A [Tomshardware thread](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/296628-28-using-video-card-slot-physx) also mentions this.

Comment: I read the question as: "My new card is going to occupy two spaces, I want to get rid of some cards for the space. What is the card in this Pcie x 4 slot?"

Answer (score 3):

The card you have pictured, and considering removing to make way for you double wide vid card looks like a TV controller card and those two back wires (look like antenna leads) may go to the front of the case where an IR sensor is probably mounted. This would allow for the remote control signal to be picked up and why they run into the box and not out or to an antenna port.

The blue and black wire may hook up to your CD/DVD or audio card.

This is your pic:

[image: your pic]

This is just a guess as the picture is pretty tough to see, and there is no way to see identifying marks like external ports, ID numbers, or even where the wires are running to.

Comment: I see how wrong I got the question. Nice answer, +1.